# configuring mock emails with commons-email

Tags: java, email, maven, configuration, apache-commons-email

I have a project using commons-email ( http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.commons|commons-email|1.2|jar ) through maven.  I would like to use the email Mocks class ( http://commons.apache.org/email/testapidocs/org/apache/commons/mail/mocks/MockHtmlEmailConcrete.html ) to write some unit tests.  However the org.apache.commons.mail.mocks package never gets included through the maven dependency.  Where can I find this package?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This class is not part of the official Apache Commons Mail API, it seems to be used internally for testing commons-email. That's why it is not part of the resulting jar and it is not available to you.

You probably need to copy over that code to your project or find some other email-mocking functionality, e.g. we are using [dumbster](http://quintanasoft.com/dumbster/) n our tests.

Comment: here is about mock , and not external library to use it

Comment: you asked what the MockHtmlEmailConcrete class is and I answered that question and additionally provided information about available alternatives, not sure why that is a problem!